# To take good qualities from your parents or elder siblings?

Tags: american-english, phrasal-verbs

If we talk about resemblance we say "take after someone" but for qualities , be it bad or good, how do we say it?

Comment: Maybe "inherit"? Some examples would really help here.

Comment: I would say that to take after someone can refer to any quality, not just physical appearance.  For example, "He's a hard worker - he takes after his father that way."

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker of American English, I agree completely with stangdon's comment:

*I would say that to take after someone can refer to any quality, not just physical appearance. For example, "He's a hard worker - he takes after his father that way."*

And given that stangdon and I speak different US dialects, that shows some cross-sectional agreement.

For qualities, usually a bad one, you can also say,

*the apple doesn't fall far from the tree.* See [this website](http://esl-bits.net/idioms/id606.htm), which also mentions two other common idioms:

*a chip off the old block*

and

*like father, like son*

These all refer to resemblance to one's parent, not a sibling.